# Is it possible to recover the original signal from an LC circuit?

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm using some photo detectors called Silicon Photo-multipliers (SIPMs) which produce a signal like the following:

[image: Original Signal]

Now, I take this signal and pass it through an LC circuit to get the following result:

[image: LC Result]

Now, my question is: is it possible to recover the original SiPM pulse, given that the only thing that I have available is its LC output?

Note: those are not the precise fits for my pulses, that's just an example of what they look like. I can post the actual signals, if required.

Comment: Great question, sorry I forgot to include it in my original question. I take the envelope of the SiPM pulse after the initial spike and then subtract that with the envelope that I fit to the peaks of the LC oscillations. I then use this subtracted result to obtain the original SiPM pulse by adding to the LC oscillations. This works for this particular case, but when I vary the amplitude of the SiPM pulse and hence of the pulse passing through the LC circuit, the same subtracted result doesn't give me the original pulse back. Instead of subtracting, I tried dividing too, but that doesn't work

Comment: that's interesting. You do not have mathematical equations of the exact waveforms. But in case you had, why not trying frequency domain methods? And also when you say LC circuit, you actually mean RLC right? So your filter response is invertable.

Comment: Well, all of this is stemming from frequency domain multiplexing. I send in a signal through an amplifier and then through an RLC circuit. But how do I get the original signal after it passes through the RLC circuits and makes oscillations? How do I invert that filter response?

Comment: @Fat32 If I pass the signal through an RLC filter, how do I invert it?

Comment: if your RLC circuit is extrmely narrow band; i.e. an ideal LC with R going to zero, then inverting could be under heavy numerical stress... is it so? can you indicate the bandwith of the signal at the input of the RLC filter, and values of R,L,C components. ?

Comment: My C is constant at 0.1 uF, R at 1 kOhm and L varies anywhere from 100 mH to 2.2 uH, which gives me a range of frequencies; anywhere from a few kHz to about a few hundred kHz. I'll have to double-check but the signal is always < 1 kHz, if I remember correctly, I'm using Hamamatsu MPPC SiPMs.

Comment: ok. what is the topology of the RLC? Is it serial or parallel, where do you get the output voltage (or current) ? and where do you apply the input. Please indicate each component position.

Comment: So my signal comes in, goes through a capacitor, I then have a junction such that an inductor goes to ground and then I have a resister after which I read my signal. Imagine signal coming in, then a capacitor and then a T such that the left top of the T is the part after the capacitor, the bottom of the T is inductor going to ground and the top right has a resistor, after which I read the signal.

Comment: you are reading the signal through 1 kOhm resistor? what's the terminating impedance of the reading end ?

Comment: I would say it's about 50 Ohms, but that's a super hand wavey guess. I could be wrong. I say this because my signal goes through an op amp, OPA 656U, which is actually not powered (but does have the feedback resistor on it) and then it goes to a  DS1054Z Rigol Digital Oscilloscope

Comment: I see... You know, one has to be quite exact and clear in defining their system, otherwise one tries to invert something that he doesn't know what it is, in the first place...

Comment: So the BNC cable that I'm using has 50 Ohms and the scope that I'm using is 1 MOhms.